# Too many requests from my IP address?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I have a bookmark folder labeled "Stack Exchanges" for the trilogy plus all of the Area 51 exchanges that are either in public beta or private beta that I'm interested in - a total of 10 sites. Every morning, before work, I sit down, open up all of them in tabs, and read through the first page or two of questions and see if there's any that I can answer. But this morning, I got a notice that my IP address had made too many requests. A quick refresh of the page loaded the site.

What's going on here? As more exchanges open, this list is going to grow to more than 10. I really don't want to cause problems, but I also don't want to trigger the next level of this error. If I routinely open 10-15 exchanges every morning simultaneously, is this going to be a problem?

Comment: I doubt this is the source of the problem. I open every morning more than 10 tabs with SO, Meta or SE stuff. Don't have any problems.

Comment: So far, it's happened once this morning. I've tried to reproduce it several times - nothing. Perhaps there might be something in the SO logs? The site where the error appeared was the Electronic Gadgets exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any browser plugins or other applications that use [the API](https://stackapps.com/) that might be making requests on your behalf?  Some of them are a little bit aggressive.

Comment: Nothing that uses the Stack API. I do use Google Bookmarks, so might Google be doing something through my bookmarks? I don't see why they would or, even if they do, why such a request would be associated with my IP address.

Comment: @Thomas: I use Google bookmarks too, but not with that many sites.  I agree that it doesn't seem likely that they're making any requests for you.  (They *might* be associated with your IP address if they were doing it in JavaScript in your browser instead of on the server, but as you said, I don't think it's Google.)

Comment: Well, it's odd since it happened once and hasn't happened again. So I've got nothing. I even spent time trying to reproduce the problem and getting no where...I suppose this question can be tagged no-repro for now and I'll just be watching out for it to happen again.