# Too many requests?

Tags: support

I went to stackexchange.com and clicked on SO.  After a few minutes I got a message saying "We have detected too many requests from this IP.  If this is an error contact us."  That was the second SE page I tried to visit.  Second only to SE.com

I moved to another machine and it's working now.  The first machine usually works, I don't know if a got assigned a blacklisted IP or what.  Anyone know what's going on?

**EDIT:** I would really rather not post my IP on the web, but if a diamond or dev asks I'll email it.

**EDIT 2:** I looked at badp's dupe suggestion and can verify that I have no scripts frequently calling SO.

Comment: Do you know the IP of the first machine?

Comment: @waiwai933: They are on the same LAN.  Do you mean the external IP?

Comment: Are your machines all sitting behind a NAT'd LAN with a single WAN IP address?

Comment: @Kev: I believe that to be correct.  So I don't know how they could block my IP and it only affect one machine...   Just checked again, the first machine works now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too many requests from my IP address?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61471/too-many-requests-from-my-ip-address)

Comment: @badp not really, this one here is better asked and have official answer, closed the other one as dupe of this one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard *points at the timestamp*

Comment: @badp http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Comment: @ShadowWizard *points at the timestamp of the comment you were originally replying to*

Comment: @badp lol, but never too late to find dupes and make the place bit more organized. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a temporary automatic ban that is put up by our HAProxy instance when you hit our rate limiter. It should only last about 5 mins. If you'd like us to take a look we'll need the public IP at the time you can email to george AT stackoverflow DOT com

Comment: Hi, how high is this rate limiter? Please.

Comment: @AnthonyMaia you really expect them to make it public??

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ins't it like wondering why a speed limit is public on signs?