# Why do the review queues mostly show 0?

Tags: support, review

Every time I go to review Late Answers or First Posts, I notice that the number of answers or questions to be reviewed is always zero.

Sometimes it will show a number, like 5, but most of the time it is zero.

Is this because the posts are actually coming but someone is reviewing them immediately or is this something else, because it will at least take a few seconds to review something right?

Comment: Keep trying....there are lots of users doing review that's why you are getting it `0`.

Comment: i tried refreshing the page again and again... Still zero... But maybe there is no one posting at that time too... Will keep trying..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You thought correctly, someone *is* reviewing them very fast! There are a lot of people reviewing at any one time, which can make finding review tasks more difficult.

If you're refreshing the Review dashboard, try going into the actual queue of either First Posts or Late Answers, and refreshing that instead.

[Auto-reload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-reload/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid?hl=en) helps. I've found you can have up to 3 queues open on a 1 second auto-reload before you hit the [Too many requests from this IP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181448/195862) block.

A nice feature of Auto-reload is that when you actually get a review item come up, it stops reloading.

Comment: Doesn't the cache refresh once every 5 seconds, though...?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of users reviewing posts, therefore you got zero in the review queue.

Click the review button repeatedly in the review section page, surely you will get more posts for review.

[image]

This is what most of the reviewers do, but don't misuse that with robo reviewing. Take a look at the posts and give some good review and help to keep the site clean.