# Got "too many requests" three times in past few hours

Tags: support, ip-ban

I've had three IP bans on Stack Overflow in the past few hours:

> We have detected too many requests from this IP. If this is an error contact us.

Doing nothing wrong.  Is there some sort of new policy?  FWIW, my system:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 60.0.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
thufir@dur:~$
```

I have a rather slow internet, but can't see how that's a problem.  I do notice that SO loads slowly, but I just did a clean install the other day.  Seems incredibly unlikely that there's a browser problem.

But, let's say Firefox is [acting odd](https://askubuntu.com/q/1043469/45156).  Let's say it's a bug.  Even then, why ban my IP address?

(No, I haven't tried Chromium yet...)

Comment: Are you on a shared IP? Company, University, popular Starbucks?

Comment: no, I'm at home.  No one else uses SO but me.  I highly doubt wi-fi is exploited, but I suppose that's conceivable...very, very remote possibility.  Installing `chromium-browser` on theory that FF is mis-behaving.  I get errors even adding this comment.

Comment: You have an error similar to ["We have detected too many requests from this IP. If this is an error contact us."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75750/158100), right? And you're not using TOR or something like that?

Comment: yes, exactly.  Pardon, should've said so.  No, not using TOR, nor any odd scripts.  Nothing like that.

Comment: Most likely your ISP shares your IP address with other people, try contacting your ISP, and ask them about it.

Comment: I don't think so, @ShadowWizard becuase it happened again.  I looked at about two questions, got banned.  Switched to chromium, opened dozens of questions, many dozens, no problem.  The correlation with browser is too strong to ignore.  I have older hardware, but it's something about FF which is triggering this -- dollars to donuts.

Comment: @Thufir in this case, you probably installed some userscript or browser addon/plugin which perform requests to Stack Exchange.