# Is the Global Status Page broken?

Tags: support, outage, stackstatus

There was just an outage of at least a portion, if not the whole, SE network. I went to the [Global Status Page](https://www.stackstatus.net/) to see what was going on and it was identified as an Outage. Now, there's no reference to this incident or outage anywhere on the page. I know it happened and I see no reason why the outage wouldn't be there and record the start time, end time, and any additional information that should be shared about it.

Comment: Very odd, I [do see the incident](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRXkX.png), however with wrong icon. (Icon means "no issues" however that was an incident, which has a different icon for it.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That was yesterday's incident

Comment: I believe the outage page is manually updated. I see the incident now.

Comment: Anyway exact same issue as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379675/how-are-maintenance-issues-logged-on-stackstatus-net), something that was there suddenly gone for some people, looks like nothing was fixed or done since then to address the issue.

Comment: @aynber I had no idea today was another outage, saw about yesterday and that there was tweet about it. So maybe they prefer to wait until they know what's going on instead of starting new incident every day, which does make sense.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard It doesn't make much sense to me. Once you call an incident or issue resolved, you wouldn't reopen it. As soon as you have other issues or incidents or outages, you'd make a new one. If you learn they are related, you can reference the older one in the newer one.

Comment: I've seen SO going offline several times in the last couple of weeks, it does seem a little unstable right now.

Comment: And now https://www.stackstatus.net/ itself is broken: ***There was an error loading the page data. Try refreshing the page or contacting support@firehydrant.io for support.*** ... and back again.  But slow.

Comment: Looks like [an issue](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8d533a56-bacb-48e3-baa5-8266d93f08c3) was eventually created. Related thread over on MSO: [What's the point in Stack Status if it (almost) always reports "All systems operational"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419510)