# Status blog doesn't show maintenance?

Tags: bug, stackstatus

As I'm attempting to view some of the featured questions on rpg.se, I get the following sight:

[image: Offline for Maintenance Status]

Because I didn't see any featured maintenance posts on meta, I decided to go to the status blog:

[image: No disruptions of service listed]

As you can see, it lists all systems as operational, even though the site is clearly undergoing maintenance.

Edit:

It's now displaying the outage status for an incident it says started 20 minutes ago. Why did it take until now for the status to display?

Comment: The status blog isn't automatic, they might add some entry there at some point in the future, and they might not. From personal experience, they don't report or log most short outages. I assume it's for security reasons, to not feed whoever is attacking the network.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. It's rather annoying that it's not automatic when they direct you to there for information about downed sites.

Comment: Well, the message does say "If this turns into an extended outage".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Global Status Page broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380810/is-the-global-status-page-broken) - It seems like the status page is very inconsistent in showing status, updating, and even showing past incidents or outages.

Comment: Hmm, initially it was more of a question of why does the status page not show maintenance, when sites are undergoing maintenance? Now I suppose the question is, why does the page offline message say that they're offline for maintenance, when they've had an outage?

Comment: And now https://www.stackstatus.net/ itself is broken: ***There was an error loading the page data. Try refreshing the page or contacting support@firehydrant.io for support.***

Comment: Related on MSO: [What's the point in Stack Status if it (almost) always reports "All systems operational"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419510/2370483)