# Stack Overflow's status page (stackstatus.net) does not mention a recent planned maintenance

Tags: bug, maintenance, stackstatus

In [Stack Overflow's status page](https://www.stackstatus.net/) it's clearly written:

[image]

However, that's just not true. There was a [planned maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382050/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-wednesday-21-september-0030-0300-utc-tues) yesterday, announced a week in advance, however it's not mentioned in the status page at all:

[image]

Taking a better look, the caption says "September 2022" however it's showing incidents from **August**, so looks like something in the dates is stuck or bugged, which might explain lack of new incidents.

Can this please be looked into?

Comment: related: [How are maintenance issues logged on stackstatus.net?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379675/how-are-maintenance-issues-logged-on-stackstatus-net)

Comment: Thanks, we’re aware the status page did not properly pull the incident from our response system, and it’s an action item on our follow-ups for this morning.

Comment: Also the "September showing August" thing seems to be a bug unrelated to the missing incident, but rather something like "the current month doesn't have any events." Now that there is a _different_ event registered in September (e.g. not the planned maintenance that is missing), [the months are organized correctly in the history page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgGvH.png) but on the home page [it's still a bit confusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hybyG.png). Added to the list.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no, I'm not talking about the history, rather how it's showing in the status homepage itself. For me it's showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY1dj.png) which is still wrong.

Comment: I think the UI is _coded_ to show the three most recent incidents, and the person who created the label assumed that there would always be at least three incidents in every two week period, maybe based on what they see across their customer base? I'm glad our incident rate is lower than the average.

Comment: Yes, acknowledged, I posted an almost identical screenshot in my amended comment.

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues at play here:

1. When the maintenance incident was created, some piece of information was missing that prevented it from being pulled into the status page.

   **We are working with the vendor on this, and will make sure that our process is correct in the future.**
2. The UI on the home page seems to be *coded* to show the three most recent incidents, but the adjacent *label* ("3 incidents in the last 2 weeks") and month title do not match. Perhaps the author assumed that there would always be at least three incidents in every two week period.

   **Arguably, the label should just be something like "Most recent incidents"** because I don't know if we should say "3" (does the list expand if there are *more* than three events in the last 2 weeks?) or "2 weeks" (since the list certainly can include events older than two weeks ago). Here is what I suggested to the vendor:

> [image]

Comment: About #2, the issue is it's showing "September 2022" title with items from August, it's not just the label itself.

Comment: About #1, no way to manually add the missing info? It's still not on the status page.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yeah I just don't think the title needs to be there at all. Like the label, it assumes that all of the recent events to show happened in the current month.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard As I said, `We are working with the vendor on this`.

Comment: Oh, thought you meant you're working about future cases to be auto added. OK then, waiting for the vendor. Thanks for all the hard work so far! :)

Comment: And as for "don't think the title needs to be there at all" yes that would be a good change, want a new feature request for that, or is it already in your list?

Comment: @Shadow Already in my list, thanks.

Comment: I see it has changed to show only the one incident from last two weeks, thanks. :)