# I'm no longer able to log in to stackoverflow.com from Login link on that site

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When I click the *Login* link on stackoverflow.com, I get redirected to this URL:

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://stackoverflow.com/`

This will give me an error for the maintenance error in the attached image.

I need to navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head` to be able to log in as normal.

[image]

#### More information

Seems like it could be localized outage in my area? My public IP address can't reach that URL, nor can my entire IP address block I purchase, nor the IP address from the VPN provider I purchased!

Canada and Netherlands areas are OK. Is it a network or DNS issue on your end?

#### Other issues

It seems like now "Login with Google" button isn't working for me because `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js?v=2a14105a7b9b` throws 503. I needed to redirect it to `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js` with this temporary Firefox plugin:

```
let pattern = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js?v=2a14105a7b9b";
let targetUrl = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js";

function redirect(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Redirecting: " + requestDetails.url);
  if (requestDetails.url === targetUrl) {
    return;
  }
  return {
    redirectUrl: targetUrl
  };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  redirect,
  {urls:[pattern]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: There's been short/periodic outages. It *should* be ok by now tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, it still doesn't work for me when I open Incognito tab in firefox.

Comment: I have rebooted, disabled sophos antivirus and it's packet filters. Still no go :)

Comment: May or may not be related: *[Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was an issue with our CDN that was localized to the Chicago region, it should be resolved now.

https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/7ee6a6f9-73b2-49f0-b9ef-b2864dda8317

Answer (score 4):

It’s not an issue on your end - I've not seen any outages on my own checks (I keep an eye out for a handful of sites), but generally that error is on SE's side. It could be our friendly DDOSer or other things, but in situations like this, unfortunately  the solution is to try again shortly.

I wouldn't say the VPN might have fixed it too, since sometimes you have issues on specific front end servers and they round robin. It’s just a combination of something going wrong on SE's end, and you hitting a server that needed fresh hamsters.

Comment: surely odd issues. trying to do the login as described in my OP then was throwing 503 on file auth.en.js?v=2a14105a7b9b which made login with google impossible. loading page without the random uuid in the auth.en.js worked for me this time hehe